# Error : Sub query returning more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a Query like

```
    select U.UserId,
           U.FirstName,
           U.lastName,
           case when (u.Department = '' or u.Department is null) then
           (select c.Client from user us 
                  inner join filter f on us.UserId = f.UserId
                  inner join client c on f.ClientId = c.ClientId)
             else
            u.Department 
            end as Client

from user U
```

when i am trying to run the above query i am getting the following error

"Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.".

Is there any alternative query i can use for the above query

thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, what are you trying to do?

Comment: can you post your tables data and what output actually you want?

Comment: I have a  User table which has department field,i wanted to get the department value if the column has non blank or null values.If the department value is blank or Null,i need to get the value from other Table Client.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the outer user table in the sub select like so:

```
select
    U.UserId,
    U.FirstName,
    U.lastName,
    case 
      when (u.Department = '' or u.Department is null) then (
        select
            c.Client
        from
            filter f
                inner join
            client c
                on f.ClientId = c.ClientId
        where
            u.UserId = f.UserId -- note refers to outer table
      ) else
        u.Department 
    end as Client
from
    [user] U
```

This will work, provided the subselect only returns one row for each user value. If it returns more than one, you need to explain more what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to, If department is null or blank at that time you need to get client from client table for respective user else Department right?
If yes then below query will help you.

```
select U.UserId,
   U.FirstName,
   U.lastName,
   case when (u.Department = '' or u.Department is null) then
   (select Top 1 c.Client from 
           filter f 
          inner join client c on f.ClientId = c.ClientId and u.UserId = f.UserId)
     else
    u.Department 
    end as Client
from [user] U;
```

Comment: This isn't valid SQL. Also using `top 1` is just papering over any problems without understanding the requirements. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/62476/4

Comment: That why I am just asking the question if yes than applied above query.
And please tell me what is invalid sql ?